# Stop page loading Python/Selenium/PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Attempting to driver.get() [this url](https://world.taobao.com/search/search.htm?_ksTS=1476211316152_41&spm=a21bp.7806943.20151106.1&search_type=0&_input_charset=utf-8&navigator=all&json=on&q=super%20mario) but it just hangs.

Is there a way I can stop this page from loading and then grab the html that was loaded?

I tried manipulating the page in various ways to load dynamic content but no matter what I do the page still hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `set_page_load_timeout`, then handle the exception:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def get_page(driver, page):
    try:
        driver.get(page)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass


def main():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
        get_page(driver, "http://your/long/url")

        print("Returned from page get")

        from pprint import pprint as pp
        pp(driver.page_source)

    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```